# iphone problem with KIssXML parser

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing

I need quick help

structure of xml is like this

```
<VacancyList generated="2011-08-26T09:06:13" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abc.com/dtd/vacancy-list.xsd"><Vacancy id="157890" date_start="2010-10-12" date_end="2011-12-31" reference_number=""><Versions><Version language="nb">
```

and I am using KissXML like this

```
DDXMLDocument *theDocument = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://pwc.easycruit.com/export/xml/vacancy/list.xml"]] options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* resultNodes = nil;
resultNodes = [theDocument nodesForXPath:@"Versions" error:&error];
```

but results is always blank.
Please help me with this

Comment: kissxml is bullsh*t library better use nsxml parser

Answer (score 1):

XML is case sensitive. You are looking for "versions" in your xpath query and not "Versions" (which is what exists in your document). I think that is your problem.

Comment: updated the code but even that is not working what else can be the problem